# Add field to observableArray after it has been loaded from API using KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, knockout.js

I have an observablearray called documents which I load with JSON from the result of an API call. I then use document to load up the currently selected document. Code is as follows:

```
self.documents = ko.observableArray();

self.document = {
    DocID: ko.observable(),
    DocName: ko.observable(),
    isDocumentEdit: ko.observable(false)  
}

function populateDocumentLocations() {
    ajaxHelper(url + '/api/Documents/' + self.businessList.busID().busID, 'GET').done(function (data) {
        self.documents(data);
    });
}

function ajaxHelper(uri, method, data) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: method,
        url: uri,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: data ? JSON.stringify(data) : null
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown);
    });
}
```

The two properties that the API returns are DocID and DocName. This all works fine. I added a third field to document (as above), "isDocumentEdit" so I know if the user has clicked the "edit" button or not (to change the GUI accordingly).

However, the value of isDocumentEdit remains as "undefined" rather than false.

I've also tried looping through "documents" and adding "isDocumentEdit = false" for each element but that didn't work.

Is it possible to add another parameter to an observable after it has been loaded? Or is there a way to load it when it makes the API call (this is where I tried to loop through and add in but didn't work)?

Comment: The issue might be case, do a console.log(data) in your populatDocumentLocations function, is "isDocumentEdit" actually "IsDocumentEdit" in your data returned from the API?

Comment: IsDocumentEdit wasn't actually returned by the API - it's something I wanted to add to the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the data comes back from the ajax call it needs to be mapped to your model that contains the observables.

First declare the Document viewModel:

```
function Document (document) {
    var self = this;

    self.DocID = ko.observable(document.DocID);
    self.DocName = ko.observable(document.DocName);
    self.isDocumentEdit = ko.observable(false);
}
```

Then you can use the jQuery $.map function to map the json response to your documents:

```
function populateDocumentLocations() {
    ajaxHelper(url + '/api/Documents/' + self.businessList.busID().busID, 'GET').done(function (data) {
        var mappedDocuments = $.map(data, function(document) { return new Document(document) });
        self.documents(mappedDocuments);
    });
}
```

This is also in the Knockout tutorial which is a good reference: http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=loadingsaving

Comment: That is an awesome answer, thank you so much! Very much appreciate the tutorial too!